# NESTED GROUP BY QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below relation:

C(id, n)
I(id,g)
IB(I_id, c_id, r)

I want to list all "n" from relation "C" in which their r equals 'H' and maximum "g" equals 't'

Sample data will be as below:

> **C:
>
>   C_ID , N**
>   c1  ,  N1
>   c2  ,  N2
>   c3  ,  N3

---

> **IB:
>
>   C_ID    , I_ID  , R**
>   c1    ,  i1   ,  H
>   c1    ,  i2    , H
>   c1    ,  i3   ,  N max H for c1 is t and m
>   c2    ,  i1   ,  N
>   c2    ,  i2   ,  H
>   c2    ,  i3   ,  N max H for C2 is m
>   c3    ,  i1   ,  H
>   c3    ,  i2   ,  H
>   c3     , i3   ,  H max H for c3 is t

---

> **I:
>
>   I_ID     , G**
>   i1   ,   t
>   i2   ,   m
>   i3   ,   t

---

> For this sample data c1 and c3 have maximum 'H' for 't'

Below query is one answer but seem it is not optimized and very heavy:

```
SELECT c1.n
FROM I ib1, C c1, I i1
WHERE i1.I_ID = ib1.I_ID
AND i1.g IN
(SELECT i.g
FROM IB ib, C c, I i 
WHERE i.id = ib.I_id 
AND c.id = ib.C_id
AND ib.r = 'H'
AND i.g = 't'
AND c.id = c1.id
GROUP BY i.g, c.id
HAVING COUNT(*)=(
SELECT max(COUNT(*))
FROM IB ib, C c, I i
WHERE i.id = ib.I_id
AND c.ID = ib.C_id
AND ib.r = 'H'
AND c.id = c1.id
GROUP BY i.g, c.id))
GROUP BY c1.id, c1.name;
```

It is appreciated to let me know what are other possible solutions and how I can optimize my query. Also it is worth to help me with my table design as well.
Thanks

Comment: It is not clear "biggest "g" equals 't'" biggest g per c.id where ib.r='H'?  What give you SELECT MAX (COUNT (*)) ?

Comment: use WITH clause, or analytic functions

Comment: but, something is not clear... you are joining table I two times and table C is joining with which table? its a Cartesian join...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, with the group by we get the count per c.id,i.g, then we 'number' the rows in descending order by count and we get only the first rows with i.g='t'

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.n
  FROM C c1
 WHERE c1.c_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT x.c_id
                   FROM (SELECT c_id, g, RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY c_id ORDER BY cnt DESC) rnmbr
                           FROM (  SELECT c.c_id, i.g, COUNT (*) cnt
                                     FROM IB ib, C c, I i
                                    WHERE i.i_id = ib.I_id AND c.c_ID = ib.C_id AND ib.r = 'H'
                                 GROUP BY i.g, c.c_id)) x
                  WHERE g = 't' AND rnmbr = 1)
```

Comment: just need a small correction at "DISTINCT c1.id" , it's DISTINCT x.id because your alias :)